# return from get function in web Api with special json format

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I return from web api special json format like this format

```
{
   "JobTitle": {
       "Sex":"?",
       "City":"?",
       "Date":"1395/06/24",
       "ActivityField":"?",
       "Salary":"?",
       "WorkHours":"?",
       "Insurance":"?",
       "Address":"?"
   },
   .
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: hi im need above json format for response in web api in asp ???ok

Comment: Still unclear what you are asking. Your tags are missing, don't have any code example. This question should be closed.

Comment: I've tagged your question with [asp.net-web-api] since you said "in asp web api" in the title, however it's still not clear what you're asking. Please elaborate more.